# Symfony2 cannot get mp3 or mp4 file from request

Tags: symfony, audio, video, file-upload

I use symfony2 to build a website that is similar to Youtube, but I got failed when I upload .mp3 and .mp4 files into my sever.

In my twig file, it looks like,

```
<form class="uploadForm" method ="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{path('mss_core_media_uploadAudio')}}">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Upload center</h2>
      <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 420px;">
          <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i> 
              <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
          </div>
          <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file">
          <span class="fileinput-new">Select</span>
          <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
          <input type="file" name="audioFile"></span>
          <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
        </div>
      </div><button class="btn btn-primary fileupload-exists" type="submit">Upload</button>
   </div>
  </form>
```

my controller code looks like,

```
$audio = $request->files->getData()->get('audioFile');
        $status = 'success';
        $uploadedURL = '';
        $message = '';
        $logger = $this->get('logger');
        $logger->debug($audio);

        if (($audio instanceof UploadedFile) && ($audio->getError() == '0')) {
```

But I got $audio is null in my action method of controller, so the rest part of code cannot be performed. I have no idea about this, I was confused that I can successfully upload an image and a pdf file by using the same method, but both audio and video files got failed.

Comment: if u r using symfony2 u can use formbuilder it will perform nicely

Comment: Does it work with other files, ie. a .jpg?

Comment: thanks guys, i figured out this, the main reason is that upload_max_filesize of php.ini is too low.